# GLSL Shaders run perfect on Intel's integrated GPU but nothing on NVIDIA

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glsl, nvidia

I'm using Geometry Shaders for Geometry Amplification.
The code runs perfectly with Intel graphics both in Windows and OS X.

I change the configs to use the dedicated NVIDIA GPU from my windows machine aaaaaaaaaaand... nothing.

This code:

```
    void testError(std::string src) {
        GLenum err = glGetError();
       if (err != GL_NO_ERROR){
           printf("(%s) Error: %s %d\n", src.c_str(), gluErrorString(err), err);
        }
    }

    ...

    printf("glIsProgram: %s\n", glIsProgram(shaderProgram)?"True":"false");
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    testError("GOGO 111");
    GLint isLinked = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, (int *)&isLinked);
    if (isLinked == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint maxLength = 0;
        glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        //The maxLength includes the NULL character
        std::vector<GLchar> infoLog(maxLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, maxLength, &maxLength, &infoLog[0]);
        printf("Program Not Linked %d:\n %s\n", maxLength, infoLog);
        //We don't need the program anymore.
        glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

        //Use the infoLog as you see fit.

        //In this simple program, we'll just leave
        return 0;
    }
```

Outputs:

```
    glIsProgram: True
    (GOGO 111) Error: invalid operation 1282
    Program Not Linked 116:
     ­Ð
```

Also the Log have a strange behaviour since it is not printing nothing but the length would be 116.

Thank you.

EDIT
This:

```
char * infoLog;
glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
```

Printed out the result.

```
Program Not Linked 116:
 Geometry info
 -------------
 (0) : error C6033: Hardware limitation reached, can only emit 128 vertices of this size
```

Which comes from:

```
const GLchar* geometryShaderSrc = GLSL(
    layout(points) in;
    layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 256) out;
...
```

It's  just weird that the Intel integrated GPUS  have less hardware (memory?) imitations that an NVIDIA GPU.
Any solution to go around this without decreasing the vertices?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to convert your std::vector to a char array for `printf` to work with it ?

Comment: Use `infoLog.data()` as the last argument of the "Program Not Linked" `printf` call.

Comment: When you copied-and-pasted that from the OpenGL Wiki, did you not notice the "Use the infoLog as you see fit." part? "as you see fit" would include useful things like *printing it out*.

Comment: you should use `glGetShaderInfoLog` for each of your shaders separately to see what s really wrong. see [complete GL+VAO/VBO+GLSL+shaders example in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) for info how to use it... not just for the linked program ... Also if your shader is the problem why you did not copy it here so we can see it ...

Comment: Thanks @LJᛃ, that printed the result.

Comment: @Spektre I was using that when I compile the shaders without any errors, the error was just n linking time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're exceeding the `GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS` limit.

In the [OpenGL 4.4 Spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) - Section 11.3.4.5 - page 388

> The product of the total number of vertices and the sum of all
>   components of all active output variables may not exceed the value of `MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS`. `LinkProgram` will fail if it determines
>   that the total component limit would be violated.

i.e `max_vertices` cannot exceed `MAX_GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS / number_of_components`

The minimum requirements are detailed in Table 23.60 - page 585

`GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS 1024`

It seems like you have 8 components, so can only have 128 vertices.  You must either decrease the number of components, or decrease the number of vertices.

Check the value of `GEOMETRY_TOTAL_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS` on each device to make sure.